# Docs and/or code issues with custom image default_attrs in wagtail?

Tags: python, wagtail

Firstly, I am using wagtail 5.2, and django 4.2.

So, I tried following the instructions in the documentation related to using default attrs.

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/77c9a3a7c29748c6ee0c7709d5a7941b1f4545a0/docs/topics/images.md?plain=1#L329-L354

I was not originally inheriting from `WagtailImagesAppConfig`, so I altered my code.  The documentation after that says to replace `wagtail.images` in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` with the path to `CustomUsersAppConfig`, and shows `wagtail.images` commented out.  I found, if I do this, then migrations referring to `wagtailimages` won't work, so `wagtail.images` needs to remain in the installed apps.

But, to make that work, due to inheritance, you need to specify a label in the app config, otherwise django will complain about `Application labels aren't unique`.  With that change made, I was able to run the server without issues.  So something like this works:

```py
class ImagesConfig(WagtailImagesAppConfig):
    name = "xxxxx.images_custom"
    label = "images_custom"
    verbose_name = "Images"
    default_attrs = {
        "loading": "lazy",
    }
```

But, then I ran into the issue that the default attrs I defined, were not getting added to picture tags.

First, I looked at how app configs are created in the django code.  The documentation says to set installed apps to the app config.  Because it is defined this way, django proceeds to create it correctly.  But I discovered that if you only have the app name (`"[APPDIRECTORYNAME].images_custom"`) and do not include the path to the app config, then django will find 2 app configs (`ImagesConfig` and `WagtailImagesAppConfig`).  It then looks on them to find one that has `default = True` set.  If it doesn't find that on any of them, then django proceeds to create an app config from its own class, which means `default_attrs` won't exist, since it isn't using the app config class.  So, if you only define the directory and app name in installed apps, then you need a default of True.

Learning that didn't help solve the problem though, my picture tags still didn't get my default attrs.  So, I looked at the code, and this line is what was added, to load the default attrs.

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/5108b5f82aabd3c2d35da92efd2afc4595e979c6/wagtail/images/models.py#L831

But, I'm unsure how this is supposed to work, since the default attrs are defined on a custom images app config, and not the wagtail images app config.  If I put a break point in the code, then I can see that if this code was loading the custom apps config, then default attrs would return correctly.

So, I believe the issues I'm having are:

1. The documentation could use some minor improvements.  I figured out what was needed, but a little improvement might make it easier for others.  If you'd like I can make a pull request for documentation changes related to this.
2. The code as well needs changing, since I don't see anything that would copy the default attrs from the custom app config to the wagtail images app config.

Is this correct?  Or, is there something I am missing?

````py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # This project
    "xxxx.documents_custom",
    "xxxx.images_custom",
    "xxxx.users",
    "xxxx.website",
    # CodeRed CMS
    "coderedcms",
    "django_bootstrap5",
    "django_sass",
    "modelcluster",
    "taggit",
    "wagtailcache",
    "wagtailseo",
    # Wagtail
    "wagtail",
    "wagtail.admin",
    "wagtail.contrib.forms",
    "wagtail.contrib.redirects",
    "wagtail.contrib.settings",
    "wagtail.contrib.table_block",
    "wagtail.contrib.typed_table_block",
    "wagtail.documents",
    "wagtail.embeds",
    "wagtail.images",
    "wagtail.search",
    "wagtail.sites",
    "wagtail.snippets",
    "wagtail.users",
    # Django
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.sitemaps",
    "django.forms",
    "anymail",
]```
````

Comment: We didn't have any issues when we started using it. Could you please post your INSTALLED_APPS showing the relative order of the app where you have your images model and then all the Wagtail apps? Note, in our case, the actual custom image model is in one of our other Django apps. The only thing in our CustomImagesAppConfig is the information for adding default_attrs.

Comment: I added the installed apps, with the project name xxxx'd out, into the question, as it was difficult to read with no newlines in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your ImagesConfig inherits from WagtailImagesAppConfig, I think you should replace `"wagtail.images"` with `"xxxx.images_custom"` in your INSTALLED_APPS. That's what I did in my project and it is working fine.

Comment: If I remove `"wagtail.images"`, then it explodes with `django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration coderedcms.0036_filmstrip_filmpanel dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('wagtailimages', '0025_alter_image_file_alter_rendition_file')`, because a codered migration depends on a wagtail images migration.  Looking at the custom images migrations, none of those depend on wagtail images.  Should codered be depending on some version number of a `"wagtailcore"` migration instead?  If so, I can make a pull request for them.